# What is the correct protocol to fix a bug to an already published app on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-developer-api

I have an app on Google Play and I tried finding resources on how to "correctly" fix a bug in my app? Do I un publish my app then upload a new APK? I tried this, but I get the message:
"Upload failed
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1."

And so I am wondering what is the correct protocol to fix a bug to an already published app on Google Play. That being said, I un published the app currently. Also, I do not feel it's necessary to update the version number because of this minor bug. Any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: You must have to chnage version code but if you don't chnage version name than your app version on app store will not be changed. 
and user get only update for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update the binary which is in google play store you must increment the version name and version number in Android manifest file. There is no other way to hack this.

Comment: Ah I see. Currently versionCode is 1 and versionName is "1.0". How do I properly change it? or could you point me to a resource?

Comment: It depends upon your mind set. You can set it as 2 and 2.0. The basic mandatory thing is it should be higher than the previous one.

Comment: You only have to increase the versionCode. versionName is only for estatics. So you could do something like: versionCode 2   versionName 1.0.1 or even keep der versionName as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Previously versions were maintained in AndroidManifest.xml file. But now in Android Studio it is handled in the app's build.gradle file.